# testnet3 node sync process is very slow

Tags: bitcoin-core, bitcoind, testnet

My config file is similar to this:

```
testnet=1
blocksonly=1
rpcport=5000
server=1
listen=0
prune=1000  
dbcache=16000 
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
rpcuser=someuser
rpcpassword=somepass
```

I have started the node sync in testnet mode and I tried to check the status by using the command

```
$ tail -f testnet3/debug.log

Ouput: 2018-04-08 04:09:51 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 46620 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 04:20:21 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 47250 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 04:30:51 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 47880 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 04:41:21 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 48510 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 04:51:51 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 49140 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 05:02:21 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 49770 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 05:12:51 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 50400 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 05:23:21 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 51030 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 05:33:51 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 51660 seconds ago)
2018-04-08 05:44:21 Potential stale tip detected, will try using extra outbound peer (last tip update: 52290 seconds ago)
```

...and keep on getting the same

Again I tried this command to see the peers info

```
$ bitcoin-cli getpeerinfo
output:
[
]
```

It means there are no peers, so I want to know what is wrong.

The syncing is happening from more than 13 hours, but still headers and blocks are 0 only.

```
$ bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
{
  "chain": "test",
  "blocks": 0,
  "headers": 0,
  "bestblockhash": "000000000xxxxxxxxxx",
  "difficulty": 1,
  "mediantime": 1296688602,
  "verificationprogress": 5.667000646249453e-08,
  "initialblockdownload": true,
  "chainwork": "0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000100010001",
.......
```

Comment: You aren't connected to the testnet network (as evidenced by having no peers), of course you aren't syncing! Can you post more of your debug.log, preferably parts where it says something about connecting to peers? If you can post all of it, that would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you running bitcoin testnet3?

put these lines to your conf file, shutdown and restart syncing again

```
addnode=104.237.131.138
addnode=151.80.205.132
addnode=192.155.82.123
addnode=74.220.255.190
addnode=80.100.203.151
```

Comment: Thanks @amaclin Now syncing is done, but pruning is taking long time.$ bitcoin-cli getblockchaininfo
error code: -28
error message:
Pruning blockstore...

Comment: I have never used pruning. Testnet spends ~13 Gb on disk - it is OK for me. AFAIK, you could prune blockchain while downloading it, not after syncing