# Testnet Bitcoin Connection refused (111)

Tags: full-node

I have ah Raspberry and i will a BTC & Lightning node set up.

my bitcoin.conf

```
testnet=3 
Bitcoind options
server=1
daemon=1
txindex=1
disablewallet=1 
 Connection settings
rpcuser=raspibolt
rpcpassword=1212431
addnode=104.237.131.138
addnode=151.80.205.132
addnode=192.155.82.123
addnode=74.220.255.190
addnode=80.100.203.151
 Raspberry Pi optimizations
dbcache=100
maxorphantx=10
maxmempool=50
maxconnections=40
maxuploadtarget=5000
```

I have the addnode from this thread:

[testnet3 node sync process is very slow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/73607/testnet3-node-sync-process-is-very-slow)

in the getnetworkinfo stands:

```
"version": 160000,
  "subversion": "/Satoshi:0.16.0/",
  "protocolversion": 70015,
  "localservices": "000000000000040d",
  "localrelay": true,
  "timeoffset": 0,
  "networkactive": true,
  "connections": 17,
  "networks": 
  "warnings": "Warning: unknown new rules activated (versionbit 28)"
```

and in the debug log stands:

```
2018-04-24 17:39:51 connect() to 85.207.214.190:18333 failed after select(): Connection refused (111)
2018-04-24 17:38:16 connect() to [2001:470:c144:cafe::a]:18333 failed: Network is unreachable (101)
```

anyone have an idea where the error lies?

my testnet port: 18333 is open.

many thanks for the help!

regards

Comment: How much time did you give it? Could take a while until it finds peers on testnet. Both errors in your log aren't to uncommon.

Comment: several days. in the debug have i peer conection:
2018-04-24 18:41:24 New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=1294178, peer=10
2018-04-24 18:41:24 New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=1294178, peer=11
2018-04-24 18:41:25 New outbound peer connected: version: 70015, blocks=1294178, peer=12
can i switch to mainnet with this error? thank for you help :)

Comment: What error? Those debug.log lines are pretty standard to see, you'll see them as nodes that were online go offline. You have active connections, what is the problem?

Comment: the error in the debug.log irritated me. connect() to 115.68.73.83:18333 failed after select(): No route to host (113)
is this not bad?

Answer (score 0):

Connection refused means there's something prevents reaching your server.

make sure that your firewall allowing connections to your port and try to add this line to your bitcoin config:

```
rpcallowip=0.0.0.0/0
```

Comment: i have add this line i n my config. in the debug log: 2018-04-25 05:11:38 Bound to [::]:18333
2018-04-25 05:11:38 Bound to 0.0.0.0:18333 but the Connection refused (111) are still there. my firewall I deactivated and the port 18333 is open. i have check under yougetsignal.com. in the debug.log have i updatetip: new best=00000000000000bd6da9189e324ba9852ea348c27f392b06a31429c783470020 height=1294289 version=0x20000000 log2_work=69.90756 tx=17934320 date='2018-04-25 05:20:26' progress=1.000000 cache=0.0MiB(356txo) Does not he get a connection to all nodes?

Comment: no dont do this, you will allow anyone to control your  client

Answer (score -1):

bitcoin-cli  -rpcbind=0.0.0.0  it works like charm

Comment: This is a bad idea. Exposing your control interface to the world is never going to be secure.

Answer (score -2):

Try to put rpcbind=0.0.0.0 in your bitcoin.conf file, it worked for me.

Comment: If you read this, don't do it. It might work but does expose a remote control of your node to [your local network and potentially] the world.

Comment: It is just a testnet.

Comment: I see everyone saying not to do this, but maybe you can also share the correct way to do it.